# Zoom to find feature

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to zoom to a feature by finding its name. I have the following code and executed then I am getting error : "Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined". Please suggest how to solve it and where I have to modify the code.

Simple Map
    
    
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

```
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
<script>

  require([ "esri/map",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/tasks/FindTask",
            "esri/tasks/FindParameters",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphicsUtils",
            "dojo/_base/array",
            "dojo/_base/Color",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FindTask, FindParameters, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, graphicsUtils, arrayUtils, Color, dom, on) {

           var map = new Map("map", {
           basemap: "streets",  
           center: [-100.275, 42.573], 
           zoom: 5
            });

        var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer");
            map.addLayer(layer);

        var findTask = new FindTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/2");

              //initialize query
        var findParams = new FindParameters();
              findParams.returnGeometry = true;
              findParams.searchFields = ["NAME", "STATE_NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007"];


              //initialize InfoTemplate
              //infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "County Name : ${NAME}<br/> State : ${STATE_NAME}<br/>Population In 2000 : ${POP2000}<br/>Population In 2007 : POP2007");

              on(dom.byId("search"), "click", getCountyDetails);

              function getCountyDetails(){

              findParams.searchText = dom.byId("county").value;               
              findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
              }

              function showResults(results){

              var polygonSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5]));

                var items = arrayUtils.map(results, function (result) {     
                var graphic = result.feature;
                graphic.setSymbol(polygonSymbol);  
                map.graphics.add(graphic);     
                return result.feature;    
              });

              var myFeatureExtent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(items);    
                map.setExtent(myFeatureExtent, true); 

            }
       });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="county" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="Get Details" />
<div id="map">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <script>

  require([ "esri/map",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/tasks/FindTask",
            "esri/tasks/FindParameters",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphicsUtils",
            "dojo/_base/array",
            "dojo/_base/Color",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FindTask, FindParameters, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, graphicsUtils, arrayUtils, Color, dom, on) {

              var map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "streets",  
                center: [-100.275, 42.573], 
                zoom: 5
              });

              var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer");
              map.addLayer(layer);

              var findTask = new FindTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer");

              //initialize query
              var findParams = new FindParameters();
              findParams.layerIds = [3];
              findParams.returnGeometry = true;
              findParams.searchFields = ["NAME", "STATE_NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007"];


              //initialize InfoTemplate
              //infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "County Name : ${NAME}<br/> State : ${STATE_NAME}<br/>Population In 2000 : ${POP2000}<br/>Population In 2007 : POP2007");

              on(dom.byId("search"), "click", getCountyDetails);

              function getCountyDetails(){
                findParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
                findParams.searchText = dom.byId("county").value;               
                findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
              }

              function showResults(results){
                var polygonSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5]));

                var items = arrayUtils.map(results, function (result) {     
                  var graphic = result.feature;
                  graphic.setSymbol(polygonSymbol);  
                  map.graphics.add(graphic); 

                  return result.feature;    
                });
                var myFeatureExtent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(items);    
                map.setExtent(myFeatureExtent, true); 
            }
       });
     </script>
```

It works fine for me! See the image belove:
[image]

This is the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Sample</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style> 
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map{
        padding:0;
      }
    </style> 
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
<script>

  require([ "esri/map",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/tasks/FindTask",
            "esri/tasks/FindParameters",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphicsUtils",
            "dojo/_base/array",
            "dojo/_base/Color",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, FindTask, FindParameters, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, graphicsUtils, arrayUtils, Color, dom, on) {

              var map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "streets",  
                center: [-100.275, 42.573], 
                zoom: 5
              });

              var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer");
              map.addLayer(layer);

              var findTask = new FindTask("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer");

              //initialize query
              var findParams = new FindParameters();
              findParams.layerIds = [3];
              findParams.returnGeometry = true;
              findParams.searchFields = ["NAME", "STATE_NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007"];


              //initialize InfoTemplate
              //infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "County Name : ${NAME}<br/> State : ${STATE_NAME}<br/>Population In 2000 : ${POP2000}<br/>Population In 2007 : POP2007");

              on(dom.byId("search"), "click", getCountyDetails);

              function getCountyDetails(){
                findParams.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
                findParams.searchText = dom.byId("county").value;               
                findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
              }

              function showResults(results){
                var polygonSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5]));

                var items = arrayUtils.map(results, function (result) {     
                  var graphic = result.feature;
                  graphic.setSymbol(polygonSymbol);  
                  map.graphics.add(graphic); 

                  return result.feature;    
                });
                var myFeatureExtent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(items);    
                map.setExtent(myFeatureExtent, true); 
            }
       });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="county" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="Get Details" />
<div id="map">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi lele3p, I have modified my code as per your suggestion and executed, but then I got new error: Map: Geometry (wkid: 4269) cannot be converted to spatial reference of the map (wkid: 102100). Please suggest how to solve this.